# ionFocus in ion-input fires twice

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have a form where some inputs have a function `(ionFocus)` and its set to `readonly` to disable the keyboard popup , anyhow, when clicked on the input it redirects to another page (modal). The problem, ONE of the inputs fires twice while the other is fine.

This is really confusing, not sure where the problem resides or if there is a better way to approach this !

In short, when clicked another page should open without any problems.

html:

```
    <form [formGroup]="trainingForm" novalidate>
     <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="labels" floating>Institution {{institution_required}}</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="institution" readonly="true" (ionFocus)="onInstituteFocus()"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
     <br>
     <ion-item>
      <ion-label class="labels" floating>Country</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="country" readonly="true" (ionFocus)="onCountryFocus()"></ion-input>
     </ion-item>
    </form>
```

ts:

```
    onInstituteFocus(){
     const institutionCtrl = this.trainingForm.get('institution');
     let ModalSearchInstitute = this.modalCtrl.create('SearchInstitutePage', {userInput: this.trainingForm.get('institution').value});
      ModalSearchInstitute.onDidDismiss(res => {
        if (res !== institutionCtrl.value){
          institutionCtrl.markAsDirty(true);
        }
        if (res !== undefined){
          institutionCtrl.patchValue(res);
        }
      });
      institutionCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();
      ModalSearchInstitute.present();
    }

    onCountryFocus(){
     const countryCtrl = this.trainingForm.get('country');  
     let ModalSearchCountry = this.modalCtrl.create('SearchCountryPage', {userInput: this.trainingForm.get('country').value});
      ModalSearchCountry.onDidDismiss(res => {
        if (res !== undefined){
          countryCtrl.patchValue(res);
        }
      });
      countryCtrl.updateValueAndValidity();      
      ModalSearchCountry.present();
    }
```

Comment: which one fires twice ?

Comment: the second one..well there is another input in between (a normal one) i just omit it here...

Comment: I have noticed that its related to the page or maybe the DOM.. if the input at the top of the page..the problem disappears. if the input is in the middle of the page or elsewhere , the problem appears... if its in the middle and you scroll until the input positioned at top of the page, the problem disappears

Comment: thats weird. does `event.stoppropagation()` work?

Comment: also how is this form submitted? maybe there is an issue there?

Comment: `event.stoppropagation()` throw an error , not a function... Also I dont think its related to submission of the form... this is happening before I attempt to submit the form... the modal page thats created on clicking on the input..is a search page that returns the selected item to the input field.

Comment: If you put $event inside the params for your event handlers in the html markup, and try logging the event in both the the Typescript methods, I wonder if the target or some other properties of the event give some pointers for the double firing.

Comment: yeah..I cleared the method and only put a log, it only fires once..apparently the modal property or creating another page causes it to fire twice... I logged the `event` but im not sure what to look for !!

Comment: Is this related? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-bundle-js-causes-ng-click-event-to-fire-multiple-times/32008  ionic.bundle.js is maybe culprit?

Comment: similar to @Yasir, I created an endless loop with an element's `(ionFocus)="myAlert()"` because dismissing the alert likely returns focus to the element.

Comment: still have the same issue in ionic 5

Answer (score 1):

First remove (ionFocus) then add (tap) event on both means on  and . It works for me.

```
<form [formGroup]="trainingForm" novalidate>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label class="labels" (tap)="onInstituteFocus()" floating>Institution {{institution_required}}</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="institution" readonly="true" (tap)="onInstituteFocus()"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
 <br>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label (tap)="onCountryFocus()" class="labels" floating>Country</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="text" formControlName="country" readonly="true" (tap)="onCountryFocus()"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>
</form>
```

Hope it is work for you.

Answer (score 1):

ionFocus is also firing twice with Ionic 4, attaching click event to ion-item would only fire every second click for a floating label item / input.

I solved it by assigning a class property when input is focused, like OP for me it is a modal. When dismissed I assigned class property as null so it can be re-opened on focus again, here is sample code:

**TS**

```
export class homePage {
  private _modal: any;

  constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController
  ) {}

  public async openModal(event): Promise<void> {
    if (!this._modal) {
      const modal = await this.modalController.create({
        component: ModalPage //change to the page you will use as modal
      });

      modal.onDidDismiss().then((data) => this._modal = null);


      this._modal = modal;

      await addressModal.present();
    }
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">Input label</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" (ionFocus)="openModal()" readonly></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution. (or rather, a workaround)

You can listen to `touchstart` event (in addition to `ionFocus` event), and then have a flag to set to on when user actually click/touch the input, and set the flag to off when the ionFocus event actually kicks off

something like:

**HTML**

```
<ion-item>
      <ion-label class="labels" floating>Country</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" (ionFocus)="onCountryFocus()" (touchstart)="onCountryTouch()"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

**TS**

```
onCountryTouch() {
   this.isTouch = true;
}

onCountryFocus() {
   if (!this.isTouch) {
     return;
   }
   // model open
   this.isTouch = false;
}
```

This will prevent the modal from re-openning when a second focus event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Add `pointer-events: none;` to the css of the input.

It should work fine as far as the input is `readonly` only as in the question.

Answer (score -1):

There is a workaround you can try. Remove (ionFocus) event and add (click) to ion-item. Also, disable your input by adding disabled tag:

```html
<ion-item (click)="onCountryFocus()" >
    <ion-label class="labels" floating>Country</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" formControlName="country" disabled></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

If you want to style your input as not disabled, add class country-input to ion-input and following css:

```css
  .country-input {
    input[disabled] {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```